# MySQL Group Epoch Timestamp by Every 15 Minutes

Tags: php, mysql, lamp

I have a database that collects some data at a pretty high frequency and records the timestamp of each entry (stored as epoch time, not mysql datetime). E.g.

```
timestamp               rssi    sender
-------------------------------------------
1592353967.171600       -67     9EDA3DBFFE15
1592353967.228000       -67     9EDA3DBFFE15
1592353967.282900       -62     E2ED2569BE2
1592353971.892600       -67     9EDA3DBFFE15
1592353973.962900       -61     2ADE2E4597B2
...
```

My goal is to be able to get a count of all the rows within 15 minute time intervals, which after research can be obtained with `GROUP BY`. Ideally, the final output would look like this

```
timestamp               count
------------------------------
1592352000 (8:00pm EST)   38    
1592352900 (8:15pm EST)   22
1592353800 (8:30pm EST)   0 <----- Important, must include periods with 0 entries
1592354700 (8:45pm EST)   61
...
```

I'm mainly having issues with 2 things here:
1. Being able to show the timestamp intervals in the results
2. Showing intervals with 0 rows within a time period

My current attempt is as follows, and it's on the right track because the data in there time periods is actually correct

```
 Showing rows 0 - 23 (24 total, Query took 0.0264 seconds.)

SELECT count(*) AS total, MINUTE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) AS minute
FROM requests
WHERE timestamp >= 1592352000 AND timestamp < (1592352000 + 3600)  
GROUP BY MINUTE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp))

total   minute  
55  32  
89  33  
64  34  
55  35  
87  36  
82  37  
90  38  
69  39  
74  40  
47  41  
89  42  
53  43  
71  44  
87  45  
72  46  
83  47  
86  48  
83  49  
113 50  
76  51  
77  52  
88  53  
81  54  
28  55
```

This data is correct, however there are periods that are not shown here (the first 30 minutes of this hour has no data and thus the first `minute` entry starts at 32). Also attempting to get every 15 minutes by using

```
SELECT count(*) AS total, MINUTE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) AS minute
FROM requests
WHERE timestamp >= 1592352000 AND timestamp < (1592352000 + 3600)  
GROUP BY MINUTE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) DIV 15

#1055 - Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'wave_master.requests.timestamp' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Given that you mention a presentation layer, consider  handling issues of data display there instead

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for the quick reply. I have thought about this but the problem is given the large amount of data, it would make sense to group it before i send it to the presentation layer, as it's going to be sent via HTTP to an ios device for display.

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: That's fine; I was more talking about the missing values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a "numbers" table to generate the 15-minute periods within the hour (0-3), and then `LEFT JOIN` that to your counts, grouped by 15 minute periods, using `COALESCE` to replace `NULL` values with 0:

```
SELECT periods.period * 900 + 1592352000 AS timestamp,
       FROM_UNIXTIME(periods.period * 900 + 1592352000) AS time,
       COALESCE(counts.total, 0) AS total
FROM (
  SELECT 0 period
  UNION ALL SELECT 1 
  UNION ALL SELECT 2
  UNION ALL SELECT 3
) periods
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT (timestamp - 1592352000) DIV 900 AS period,
         COUNT(*) AS total
  FROM requests
  WHERE timestamp >= 1592352000 AND timestamp < 1592352000 + 3600
  GROUP BY period
) counts ON counts.period = periods.period
```

Output (for the data in your question plus a couple of other values):

```
timestamp   time                    total
1592352000  2020-06-17 00:00:00     1
1592352900  2020-06-17 00:15:00     1
1592353800  2020-06-17 00:30:00     5
1592354700  2020-06-17 00:45:00     0
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xjzQ85j5KNkMQ7VEhuH8G7/0)